# question regarding hash

Tags: algorithm, collections, hash

hash access time is best time O(1) and worst case O(n). I am wondering what's the average case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a hash that isn't nearing full the average case is roughly O(1).  The details depend a bit on how collisions are resolved and how full the hash is.  Usually efficiency starts really decreasing around 80% capacity.

Comment: doesn't this depend upon the efficiency of the hashing algorithm with respect to the particular set of keys found in the current data. You could get really unlucky, see unexpectedly high collisions.

Comment: Also depends what you count. For instance, if your keys are strings, and if you're adding N distinct keys to the hash, then N distinct strings are of average length at least Omega(log N). Chances are your hashing algorithm is Omega(length of string), so it's Omega(log N) per key just to hash it, as part of a lookup or insert. That's still O(n) total though where n is the total size of the data, rather than the number of elements in the hash (which I've called N).

Answer (score 0):

In practice, *O*(1).
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Performance_analysis